# How to generate a compressed file with content larger than disk free space?

Tags: compression

I want to do this simple task:
print as many 'a' to a file as possible. (and let's say we accept the final output is a tar file)

my naive solution is:

1. use a simple script to print 'a' to a file output.txt, we generated say a 1GB file with all 'a' in it.
2. use
   tar -cvjSf output.tar.bz2 output.txt, the result is a 1kb file.

now I want to kick this up a notch: increase the size of the compressed file. but my disk space only have, say, 300GB free space, does that limit the final size of the tar file? or is there a trick to not let the free space be a limitation?

Comment: Just feed the output of your generator straight into the compressor (e.g. pipe it in). Or write a simple program, say in Python that creates an instance of `zlib`, `gzip` or `bzip2` and just `write`s the generated data to it.

Comment: Thanks Dan! I have 2 followup qn: 1. how to pip the stdout of my python script to a tar command?  2. do you know what python library does this task?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html ? :D Or `subprocess` if you want to run an arbitrary program.